# Secrets Manager environment variables in AWS CodeBuild echoing as "***" in the build logs

Tags: aws-codebuild, aws-secrets-manager

I'm trying to get Secrets Manager secrets into my AWS CodeBuild server via environment variables.  I believe I have permissions taken care of (giving the service role the `secretsmanager:GetSecretValue` permission), as I no longer get any permissions errors.  When I `echo` my Secrets Manager environment variables to the build log to see if everything is working well, though, the secrets display as `"***"`.  Also, my subsequent command using these variables is failing, so I'm guessing that I don't ***really*** have the valid secrets values after all.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this helps anyone else in the future.

I saved these environment variables to a file on the build server and then uploaded it to an S3 bucket.  I looked in the file and the real values ***are*** there.  So it seems that the `"***"` is just a security measure to hide these values in the build server log.

Therefore, my problem lies elsewhere, but at least I know where it isn't!  :-)